# What is the basic layout of a webserver?

Tags: php, html, mysql, webserver

Hi Im wondering how to make a basic directory layout for a client if you have php and mysql embeded. I mean the folder layout, and how to name them. So that everyone that develops in the web can recognize it. Is there any special way to do this?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic can mean a lot here. The most basic web hosts I worked with just have one folder in it. www (or htdocs, httpdocs, public_html, html) The domain is configured to point into this folder. All files are accessible from the web. Older webservers often had separate folders for perl, cgi, python, etc. stuff. More advanced server offer more folders, for example for logs, automated backups. It can be a good practice for some frameworks to have a separate folder for the source files and create a symlink in the public folder. It really depends on what you want to offer to your client. I would suggest to first of all make a plan on what you want to offer and then try to build a folder structure that mirrors a modular server build. For naming conventions, there are no real standards.

Comment: Thank you <3 very much